# Problem with the calculation of Lyapunov exponents

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, numerics

I am trying to calculate the Lyapunov exponents for the orbit of two bodies around each other. Therefore, I use the following code:

```
Import["lce.m"];
hameq[{R_, θ_, Φ_, pr_, pθ_, 
pΦ_}] := {4.9244594652595943`*^8 pr, (
1.0742851132788298`*^15 pθ)/R^2, (
1.0742851132788298`*^15 pΦ Csc[θ]^2)/
R^2, -0.004429986713039174` (1477.`/R^2 + 
1/2 (-((4.850060204996962`*^17 pθ^2)/R^3) - (
4.850060204996962`*^17 pΦ^2 Csc[θ]^2)/R^3)), (
1.0742851132788298`*^15 pΦ^2 Cot[θ] Csc[θ]^2)/
R^2, 0}
{1.4709*10^11, π/2, π/2, 0., 0.0296727, 0.};

xo = {1.4709*10^11, π/2, π/2, 0., 0.0296727, 0.};
t = 6.403*10^12;
K = 10;
stepsize = 19*10^10;
TR = 0;
lceshameq = LCEsC[hameq, xo, t, K, TR, stepsize];
```

which seems to follow the general procedure of the package (cf. http://www.msandri.it/soft.html).
However, I always, even when I vary the parameters of the simulation, get the errors:

Last::nolast: {} has zero length and no last element.

Part::pkspec1: The expression Last[{}] cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression 1+Last[{}] cannot be used as a part specification.

I neither know where they come from, nor what they mean. 
Thank you for the help!

Comment: I get only the Last::nolast error, which is usual for this package (although the six exponents are of the order of $10^{-12}$ at most). Try quitting the kernel, maybe you have some old definitions. Moreover, you might want to try an [updated version](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7109/), employing MMA's `NDSolve`.

Comment: Hi corey, thanks, now it works for me too. You saved me some more hours of desperation. That's a nice, simple solution... But how could that be possible? All the examples of the package I tried worked out without any errors. And, should I delete my question, since it is completely meaningless?

Comment: Btw, Sandri's package is deprecated, e.g. it uses `K`, which is a protected symbol: "K is a default generic name for a summation index in a symbolic sum." The updated version is safer.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I will give it a try.